# What is $\mathbb{F}_p(\sqrt{X})\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p(X)} \mathbb{F}_p(\sqrt{X})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, modules, tensor-products

I am trying to understand what $\mathbb{F}_p(\sqrt{X})\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p (X)} \mathbb{F}_p(\sqrt{X})$ is. $\mathbb{F}_p(\sqrt{X})$ is the field of rational functions in $\sqrt{X}$. What is it isomorphic to? Is it a field?

I noticed that $\mathbb{F}_p (X)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_p (\sqrt X)$. But I am not very sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Actually, $\mathbb{F}_{p}(X)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X})$. The latter is obtained by adjoining a root of $T^{2}-X \in \mathbb{F}_{p}(X)[T]$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim I was thinking that if you have $K(\sqrt{X})$, you can simply get $X$ by $\sqrt{X}\times\sqrt{X}$?

Comment: Right! So certainly $\mathbb{F}_{p}(X)$ lives inside $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X})$, no? :)

Comment: @AlexWertheim Oh...Right, so not the other way around -_-" haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to one of your previous questions. Note that $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X}) \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}(X)[T]/\langle T^{2}- X\rangle$. This polynomial is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion, and is separable if $p \neq 2$. In this case, we have
$$\mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X}) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_{p}(X)} \mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X}) \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X}) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_{p}(X)} \mathbb{F}_{p}(X)[T]/\langle T^{2} -X \rangle \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X})[T]/\langle T^{2}-X\rangle$$

As noted above, if $p \neq 2$, then $T^{2}-X$ factors as $(T+\sqrt{X})(T-\sqrt{X})$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X})$, so by the Chinese Remainder Theorem,

$$\mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X})[T]/\langle T^{2}-X\rangle = \mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X})[T]/\langle (T-\sqrt{X})(T+\sqrt{X}) \rangle \cong  \\
\mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X})[T]/\langle (T-\sqrt{X}) \rangle \times \mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X})[T]/\langle (T+\sqrt{X}) \rangle \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X}) \times \mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X})$$

On the other hand, if $p = 2$, then $T^{2}-X$ factors as $(T-\sqrt{X})^{2}$, so $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X})$ is not a separable extension of $\mathbb{F}_{p}(X)$. In this case, I don't know what progress one can make in simplifying the tensor product in question - it may not have a nice description.

Comment: It all makes sense except I don't understand the second isomorphism on line 4.

Comment: @Misakov: is this clearer?

Comment: I see similarity between this question and the previous question. In the previous question, I made sense of $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{2}-2) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}(i) \cong \mathbb{Q}(i)[X]/(X^{2}-2)$ by mapping basis "basis to basis". Does that work here as well?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X}) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_{p}(X)} \mathbb{F}_{p}(X)[T]/\langle T^{2} -X \rangle \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X})[T]/\langle T^{2}-X\rangle$, not the chinese remainder theorem part.

Comment: @Misakov: that should work. They're manifestations of the same phenomenon - tensoring two extensions of the same field over that field. Is that line clear now?

Comment: Sorry I am still confused...In the $\mathbb{Q}$ case I can tell that they are really just $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$ but what about this case?

Comment: @Misakov: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Are you confused why $\mathbb{F}_{p}(\sqrt{X}) \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}(X)[T]/\langle T^{2} - X \rangle$, or are you confused about one of the isomorphisms?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42518/discussion-between-misakov-and-alex-wertheim).